# How to share s3 bucket to all my instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, s3fs

I have mounted my S3 bucket to my original Instance and I am able access the files. Then I made copy of my Original Instance using **Launch More Like This** from AWS Console UI. Again I mounted the same S3 bucket to the new Instance but I am unable to access files in the new Instance.

PS: AWS Beginner

Comment: Please provide more detail.  What is the error you are getting?  How did you mount the S3 bucket to your instance?  Help us help you.

Comment: using s3fs I mounted my S3 bucket. While accessing s3 bucket after mounting I am getting Segmentation fault error

Comment: Are there any other details associated with the segmentation fault, e.g. address, object, etc. in the logs?

Comment: Nothing just "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: Is there a way to mount s3 bucket using javascript aws-sdk?

Comment: Using "Launch more like this" does not copy a running EC2 instance. It launches a new instance from the same AMI as the original instance, gives it the same IAM role and same userdata etc. Specifically, if you installed or configured things on the original EC2 instance *after* launch then those will not be present on the new instance. PS no, EC2 cannot mount the S3 bucket using an AWS SDK.

Comment: It looks like s3fs encountered some kind of error. Could you run it in the foreground with debug logs via `-f -d`? Also please try with the latest release version 1.85.